# No module named 'sleep'

Tags: python

first of all this is my first post so I'm sorry if there's anything I didn't do in order to make it easier to answer to my question.

I am trying to make the program wait for a couple of seconds before moving on to the next piece of code. However I've looked on the internet about my issue but can't seem to find a solution.

This is my code:

```py
from time import sleep

print("Hello")
time.sleep(3)
print("World")
```

But it returns this ModuleNotFoundError instead:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sleep'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just `import time` and use `time.sleep(3)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
from time import sleep

print("Hello")
sleep(3)
print("World")
```

Since you import only `sleep` from the module, you cannot use `time.sleep(3)`, since the module `time` is not imported.